# how to make sortable datatype in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures

I have a class representing something with a few fields. When a list of instances of this class is sorted, I want them to be sorted in a particular order (get a particular key from each one). I can just do `list.sort(key=Classname.sortKey)` and define a `sortKey` method, but I'd rather just do `list.sort()` and have it work out. I figure I can do this by overriding `__cmp__`. However, what do I do when I'm comparing with something that is not my data type? I figure something like...

```
def __cmp__(self, o):
    if isinstance(o, MyClass):
        return cmp(self.sortKey(), o.sortKey())
    return object.__cmp__(self, o) ##**wrong
```

but that works instead. I don't care what ordering they take in a heterogeneous list. I would just return `0` but then stuff like `MyClass(...) == x` is always true, for any `x` not an instance of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

You want to override `__lt__` in your class for the built in `sort` function to work the way you described.